# Limit of an integral with parameter

Tags: calculus

I am studying integrals with parameters and I have come across a problem. In a book there is a solved example:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{R \to \infty} = \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin x} \, dx
\end{equation}
And it is solved in a way where we simplify the integral with taking upper approximations:
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin x} \, dx \leq\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-(R/2) x} \, dx
\end{equation}
And then the integral is solved and limit calculated. My question is, **when** can I make these upper approximations to simplify the integral?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simplification of the integral, but rather an inequality that relates the integral to a simpler integral.

The reason it can be used to find the limit is this:
$$
0 \le \int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin x} \, dx \leq\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-(R/2) x} \, dx \to0 \text{ as } R\to+\infty.
$$
The point is that if a function of $R$ is between $0$ and another function of $R$ that approaches $0$, then that function that is squeezed between those two also approaches $0.$

Comment: Oh, so basically (in general) I need to find a function that intercepts with the "original" one at the integral bounds?

Comment: @Murg : No. You just need some function of $R$ concerning which you can show that the integral you started with is squeezed between $0$ and that function of $R,$ and for which you can show that that function of $R$ approaches $0.$ Then you can conclude that the integral you started with approaches $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the useful inequality

$$(\forall x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}])\;\;\;  \frac{2}{\pi}x\le \sin(x)$$

and

$$e^{-R\sin(x)}\le e^{-\frac{2R}{\pi}x}$$

Thus

$$0\le\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-R\sin(x)}dx\le \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-Ax}dx$$

$$=\frac{-1}{A}\Bigl[e^{-Ax}\Bigr]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{e^{-R}-1}{R}$$

where $ A=\frac{2R}{\pi}$.

Your limit is zero.

Comment: Yes that is clear to me. My question is, how do I know when can I make approximations like this? Are there any special conditions that must apply?

Comment: @Murg Ok, i edited new lines. Now integrate both sides.

Comment: I am sorry. My question wasn't directed at how to solve this specific problem but more to when can I (in general case) make this kind of inequality to translate an original integral to a simpler integral.